# Detecting background image top margin with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I detect the top margin of a div and increase/decrease it:

```
var oldm = $("#bdi").css("margin-top").replace("px", "");

var addm = 1;

$("#bdi").css({
'margin-top': '-='+addm+'px'
})
```

But I need to do the same with background position.

1. detect the actual top position of a background image
2. increase/decrease the top margin of a background image

For example:

```
background-position: center 5px;
```

How do I detect "5px" and increase/decrease it?

Thanks

Comment: I know how to retrieve a value if there is only one value. But I don't know how to retrieve the seconf value and to increase/decrease the second value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript or jquery get background-position properties of a given element and then +/- to that dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011286/javascript-or-jquery-get-background-position-properties-of-a-given-element-and-t)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044361/how-do-i-convert-a-css-background-position-property-from-percentages-into-pixels

Comment: @user1406271 See my answer and say your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. [Link](http://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc-1)

For example like this

```
$("div").css("background-position-x", "+=10px");
$("div").css("background-position-Y", "-=10px");
```

If you want to do other operation on css value use this

```
$("div").css("background-position-x", function(index) {
    return index * 10;
});
```

You can see demo at bottom

```js
$("#increaseX").click(function(){
    $("#image").css("background-position-x", "+=10px");
});
$("#decreaseX").click(function(){
    $("#image").css("background-position-x", "-=10px");
});
$("#increaseY").click(function(){
    $("#image").css("background-position-y", "+=10px");
});
$("#decreaseY").click(function(){
    $("#image").css("background-position-y", "-=10px");
});
```

```css
#image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/28536");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
<button id="increaseX">increaseX</button>
<button id="decreaseX">decreaseX</button>
<br />
<button id="increaseY">increaseY</button>
<button id="decreaseY">decreaseY</button>
```

Firefox doesn't support `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`. If you want to do your target work in firefox, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dkL0pn1/)

You can

Comment: background-position-x, background-position-y don´t work in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using background-position-y like this :

```
var bgPositionY = ($("#bdi").css('background-position-y'))
var addPos = 5;
$("#bdi").css({
'background-position-y': '-='+addPos+'px'
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/aLkok1n4/

Comment: It returns bgPositionY -> undefinied

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this...

```
var el = document.getElementById('bdi'),
    currentYPosition = getComputedStyle(el)['backgroundPositionY'],
    increment = 1,
    newYPosition = 'calc(' + currentYPosition + ' + ' + increment + 'px)';

// Set new backgroundPositionY
el.style.backgroundPositionY = newYPosition;
```

The use of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) above ensures the value is properly incremented, even if a percentage position value is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, the simplest option is to use incremental notation inline:

```
$("#bdi").css('background-position-y', '+=5px');
```